# need help with limits and little-oh

Tags: limits

I am reading the proof of a statement where limits are used with little-oh' s. There are two parts I need help with:
Suppose $g (n, k) $ is a non-increasing function wrt $ n$ and $ f (k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{g (n, k)}{{{n}\choose{k}}  }}$.

Why

1. $ g (n, k)\leq f (k){{n}\choose{k}} + \hbox{o} \left(n^k\right)$
2. $ f (k){{n+c}\choose {k}} + \hbox{o}\left(((n+c)^k\right) = f(k){{n}\choose {k}} + \hbox{o} \left(n^k\right) $?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to write 1. $g(n,k) = f(k) (n; k) + o(n^k)$? (I donno how to do the "n over k".

Comment: There seems to be too much of it on the left. Because if $f(k) = \lim_{n \to \infty} g(n,k) / (n;k)$ then $g(n,k) / (n;k) = f(k) + o(1)$ as $n \to \infty$. Multiplying by the binomial coefficient $(n; k)$ and estimating it (how? cf. wiki) gives 1.

Comment: There is indeed something fishy about the presence of $\binom{n}{k}$ on the left side of 1. Also, little-oh statements are always about limits. Here, it seems to be about the limit as $n\to\infty$. If $k$ is kept fixed throughout, this is fine; but otherwise, there is some reason to worry.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry about that, there is just g (n, k) on left. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We keep $k$ fixed throughout, and find
$$\frac1{n^k}\binom{n}{k}=\frac1{k!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{n-j}{n}\to\frac1{k!}\quad\text{when $n\to\infty$}.$$
By assumption $f(k)=g(n,k)/\binom{n}{k}+o(1)$, and multiplying through we get $$g(n,k)=f(k)\binom{n}{k}+o\Bigl(\binom{n}{k}\Bigr)=f(n,k)\binom{n}{k}+o(n^k)$$
by the first result. So we have #1 with *equality*, not merely an inequality.

#2 has nothing to do with $f$ or $g$, since $k$ is kept fixed. It is equivalent to
$$\binom{n+c}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+o(n^k)$$
(note that $(n+c)^k/n^k\to1$ as $n\to\infty$), and this follows from $\binom{n+c}{k}/n^k\to1/k!$ and $\binom{n}{k}/n^k\to1/k!$.

Comment: If you look at this carefully, I think you can get #1 with the original inequality, uniformly in $k$ – provided that the originally assumed limit is a uniform limit. By $o(n^k)$ as $n\to\infty$ uniformly in $k$, I mean a quantity which, after division by $n^k$ goes to zero as $n\to\infty$, uniformly wrt $k$.